# I am trying to to convert my variables to categorical using to_categorical method in keras and facing the issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Keras, Tensorflow and did not find any solution.

```
    from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
    Y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=None)
    Y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=None)
    print(Y_train.shape)
```

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\Anaconda3\envs\nnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
         57 
    ---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
         59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-3cac28c3a2f2> in <module>()
```

Answer (score 0):

For keras newer keras versions use `from keras.utils import to_categorical`.

If you have older keras try to install np_utils with:

```
pip install np_utils
```

and **restart** the kernel after installation.

Comment: I did as you said and it is not working. I just tried importing Keras library and the same error is repeating. I installed Keras using pip and it is successfully installed.

Comment: Using Anaconda?

Comment: Yeah, I am using Jupyter-notebook(anaconda). I created an environment of Python 3.5 with all the requirements installed in it and using it since keras is not available in 3.7.

Comment: pip and anaconda is not working sometimes, try with --force_reinstall